# No POSTS appearing on XAMPP

Tags: php, post, xampp

Similar questions to this have appeared before, but they do not answer my issue. POST just seems to have --- gone!

I was trying to setup typeahead (data form filling), but it was behaving strangely, and this would appear to be why.  Jquery/Ajax is not called from these test pages.

The sending page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<head>
  <title>Test2</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="myform.php" method="POST">
   <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></p>
   <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The receiving page:

```
<?php
echo 1;
echo $_POST['firstname'];
echo $_POST['lastname'];
echo 2;
?>
```

Fill in a firstname and lastname, press [submit], and out comes:

```
1
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\develop0\247mytown\www\test\typeahead\myform.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\develop0\247mytown\www\test\typeahead\myform.php on line 5
2
```

I am using W10, PHP Version 7.4.11, XAMPP 2.4.46.0 - and phpinfo tells me: enable_post_data_reading set to On and On.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the page just calling itself?

Comment: What is the value [of `variables_order`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) from phpinfo? And are these two distinct files, or is the PHP in the same page as the html?

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: You open the `<head>` section twice, but only close it once.

Comment: @JasonK - two separate, very small, pages

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski variables_order is GPCS

Comment: @droopsnoot - array(0) { }

Comment: @droopsnoot Bad copy of the code, it's only in the code once.

Comment: It's not only happening on these pages, it was the same on all the pages that I was testing, so I created this  "simplification" of my issue.

Comment: Now THIS is weird. As far as I can see (and it's late here, so I will check tomorrow) - the answer is in the .htaccess file. 
Removing these three lines in the next post, starts it working again!


The only way I figured this out, was by trying it on a different virtual host domain, where the code worked. There are no .ini for these domains, so it must be in .htaccess - which is different for each v_host.


Losing the $_POST values in the redirection,  perhaps.

Comment: The lines were 

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L] :::  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f :::
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the $_POST variables were not being posted when using a simple form, because in .htaccess there was a line which forwarded the visitor to a different page. This line is:

RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [R,L]

This removes the .php from the URL - don't ask me why! In fact, there was a line a little lower down, which adds the .php back on!

But (as far as I can see) if you forward a file, the POST information is lost.